# The number of zeros of a function regular on the closure on $U$ and the max of $\operatorname{Re}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f(z)$ is holomorphic on the closed unit disk $\bar U$ and never vanishes on the boundary $\partial \bar U$. Prove that the maximum of $\displaystyle \operatorname{Re}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}\geq\#\mbox{zeros of $f(z)$ in the unit disk.}$

Thoughts: By the [argument principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle)$\displaystyle \int_{\partial \bar U}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\mathrm{d}z=2\pi i\,\#\mbox{zeros}$. There is a similarity between the pattern of $\frac{f'}{f}$ and $\frac{zf'}{f}$, plus $\displaystyle\int \frac{zf'}{f}\mathrm{d}z=2\pi i\sum\mbox{roots}$ as a consequence of the argument principle. This might give us some ways. Another idea is to use the Borel-Caratheodory inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume there is a typo in you question and the real question is how to show
the maximum of $\Re\left[ \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}\right]$ over $\partial\bar{U}$ is greater than or equal to the number of zeros over $U$. Otherwise, your question is simply false.

In any event, you don't really need anything complicated. You just need to rewrite the formula for number of zeroes as an integral over $[0,2\pi]$.
$$
\begin{align}
\#\text{zeroes} 
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \bar{U}} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz
=  \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{i\theta} f'(e^{i\theta})}{f(e^{i\theta})}d\theta
=  \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \Re\left[\frac{e^{i\theta} f'(e^{i\theta})}{f(e^{i\theta})}\right]d\theta \\
&\le \max_{z\in\partial\bar{U}}\,\Re\left[ \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}\right]
\end{align}
$$

Comment: you are right there was a typo. sorry for that

Comment: You answer is right. Thanks.